# Looking for precise steps on how to build a website for someone who wants to maintain control of his domain and hosting?

Tags: wordpress, dns, cpanel

I am looking for optimal way to build a website for someone who owns his domain already, as well as his hosting, and wants to keep control of both.

I would most likely be setting up his website with Wordpress. Looking for tips from experienced web developers.

Can I do it with an addon domain in Cpanel?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: don't use Wordpress.

Step 2: hire a developer.

Step 3: be fair to the developer.

Step 4: relax, the developer has your back

Comment: Do you really Wordpress is that limited? Sure, it lacks the versatility a real developer might have, but don't you think it can provide a professional enough look and framework for most individuals. Always interested in picking people's brains. Thanks

Comment: It's never a good idea to build a website from CMS. You end up building it within the limitations of the CMS. Instead build the CMS for the data of the website. This way, the capabilities of your site is never limited. The versatility of a real developer over something that's good enough for most individual is like telling your customers "yes, we can do anything" over "we can only do this". It's a matter of you providing a complete service over a service that's good enough. Hey, if your standard is capped at just good enough, then by all means, use Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

at wordpress.com , they host your website.

But if you go to wordpress.org -> Download wordpress cms files -> Upload and install it on your own cpanel hosting, then you will have full control over your wordpress installation.

Now if your client/friend has his own domain and hosting. You can just install wordpress in their hosting.

If he got cpanel, It may have very easy 1 click installation tools to install wordpress. look for it.

Reply here if you have anymore questions. Regards

Comment: Yes I think 1 click installation on their Cpanel makes the most sense. Thanks!